# Selecionar variáveis regressão logística

Tags: r

Sou novato no `RStudio` e estou tendo dificuldades para simplificar meu código. Estou fazendo uma regressão logística e gostaria de selecionar apenas as variáveis com p<0.20. Para isso, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
imcbi <- glm(data2$desfechouti ~ data2$imc, family=binomial())

localbi <- glm(data2$desfechouti ~ as.factor (data2$local), 
family=binomial())

readmbi <- glm(data2$desfechouti ~ as.factor (data2$readm), 
family=binomial())
```

Rodo separadamente e faço depois:

```
summary(imcbi)
summary(localbi)
summary(readmi)
```

Existe como eu montar o código para que a análise bivariada seja toda feita junto de modo que eu precise depois apenas de UM comando `summary`?

Lembrando que estou selecionando as variáveis para montar meu modelo de regressão logística.

Comment: Utilizar a Regressão Logística LASSO para selecionar variáveis pode ser uma alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Tente ajustar um modelo de regressão logística com todas as variáveis preditoras simultaneamente:

```
modelo <- glm(desfechouti ~ imc + as.factor(local) + as.factor(readm),
  data = data2, family = binomial())
summary(modelo)
```

Ao utilizar a sintaxe `glm(formula, data = data2)` não é necessário colocar o nome do data frame antes de cada variável chamada no ajuste.

Comment: Entendi, Marcus. O problema é que corro o risco de incluir variáveis que não são relevantes nem na analise bivariada. Na minha tabela eu conto com mais de 30 fatores, por isso queria uma forma simples de escrever esse código. Vou seguir tentando. Brigado pela sugestão.

Comment: Não leve a mal o que vou escrever agora, mas a informação "Na minha tabela eu conto com mais de 30 fatores" não estava na pergunta original. Existem métodos capazes de lidar com seleção automática de variáveis mesmo com um número elevado delas. Fazer da  maneira como foi proposta, com mais de 30 regressões independentes, além de trabalhosa, é errada, pois infla a taxa de falsos positivos. Seja mais detalhado na pergunta pra que tu obtenha a ajuda necessária para resolver o teu problema específico.

Comment: Peço desculpas pela forma que me expressei. O que queria dizer era que ainda não cheguei no modelo de GLM e sim estava tentando selecionar as variáveis. Sei que existem métodos para montar a regressão logística (stepwise forward, backward, etc etc) mas mesmo assim você precisa selecionar as variáveis cuja análise bivariada apresenta um p<0.2 (ou qualquer que seja o seu corte). Pelo menos é assim que a maior parte dos artigos em Medicina o fazem. Sigo na busca de um código mais amigável (o atual está girando em torno de 1000 linhas). Valeu pela ajuda.